# How does WordPress determine which multisite the user is on from the URL?

Tags: multisite, code, customization, php

What is the file and line where WordPress determines which multi-site the user is on from the URL?

I've been looking through the code all afternoon and can't figure out where it turns `mysite.com/blogbase/myblog` into `2` (the ID). There's a `get_id_from_blogname()` function, but it doesn't seem to be called on load?

Answer (score 1):

Took a little while to run through, but this is where we end up.

On line 85 of `wp-settings.php`, it checks if the `MULTISITE` constant has been defined. If so, it loads the multisite files that handle things like figuring out which blog you are on.

One of those files is `/wp-includes/ms-settings.php`. I believe it decides which blog you are on at line 50.

```
$current_site->blog_id = $wpdb->get_var( .... 'SELECT blog_id FROM ... WHERE path = ...' );
```

Basically, `$current_site` is a global stdClass that gets returned from `wpmu_current_site()`. In `ms-settings.php` it overwrites it if it hasn't already been forced via config settings.

Also check out `/wp-includes/ms-load.php` for info on `wpmu_current_site`

Comment: I'm not sure what `wpmu_current_site()` is actually doing, but the `$current_site` variable it returns always has the same `$current_site->domain` and `$current_site->path`, regardless of which blog I'm on. It's always `[path] => /wordpress/ [blog_id] => 1`. Later in `wpmu_current_site()` it sets $path from `$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]`, but that code never seems to run since the function always returns before that. The constants being used are coming from `wp-config.php`. So I'm still not sure where it's getting the path from the URL at...